# Get data from plugin People list in author template

Tags: plugins, author-template

I use Theme Mystique for my site, and the plugin [People list](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/people-lists/).

I have created several new fields for the profiles of authors in the plugin.
Now I want to get these fields in the authors template. 
How do I do that?